# Execute two Monos in parallel but processing them individually

Tags: java, parallel-processing, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to execute two Monos in parallel(like the code below) but process each Mono individually with doOnNext for each Mono. I have tried to use Mono.zip but it is not useful for my case because if one of them emits no data, the lambda function for the Mono.zip specified is not executed and for my case I need to do some processing even if any of the Monos emits no data. Thanks!

```
var mono1 = client.findId(nameClient)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
        
var mono2 = shop.findId(nameShop)
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
    
var result = Mono.zip(mono1, mono2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "process each Mono individually"? You can just add required logic for every `Mono` (mono1 & mono2). as for empty - `Mono.zip` doesn't support empty responses and you would need to report some value. As an option you can return `Mono<Optional<T.>` and then handle it accordingly

Comment: I mean execute them in parallel and process the monos with values or empty values.

Comment: You code looks parallel already. I mean, it could depend on the other logic, but this part could be parallel if you use it like just that. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: I mean execute them in parallel and process the monos with values or empty values, I dont want to use zip because if one of the Mono emits no data, the lambda function associated to the zip function wont be executed.

Comment: Can you show how exactly you "execute" them. It seems that's where the problem is located

Comment: where can I attach you the code?

Comment: @fernando1979 You can _edit_ the question. Please add the _execution_ part to the question.